# What does KeyboardView.closing() do?

Tags: android

Does anybody know what KeyboardView.closing() does? It is undocumented, or rather it's description in the documentation is blank (like sooooo many other methods).

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what it looks like internally ([source](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java.shtml)):

```
public void closing() {
    if (mPreviewPopup.isShowing()) {
        mPreviewPopup.dismiss();
    }
    removeMessages();

    dismissPopupKeyboard();
    mBuffer = null;
    mCanvas = null;
    mMiniKeyboardCache.clear();
}
```

By the look of it, it does what you might expect. It clears the keyboard cache, the bitmap image used in the rendering of the keyboard and dismisses the virtual keyboard if it's showing.

Comment: Thank you, but I already looked at the source code. All of those commands refer to the _popup_ keyboard (such as may be used to display extra keys), but it does not close the main keyboard. My best guess is that it is preparing the main keyboard for closure at some future time but I cannot tell for sure. Google uses closing() in their API examples but it is mysteriously undocumented.